# SQL Loop that assigns a new variable for single column of row data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a stored procedure for SQL Server that allows me to submit row data for multiple 'locations'. I am having trouble finding a way to write a script that will submit the static data while integrating a new variable for the 'location'.

I have 6 variables and I need only one variable to update with submission of row data. As of now, I have a procedure that works great for single submissions.

```
@BarcodeID, @TaskNotes, @Location, @UserID, @Job, @Deadline
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tbl_TaskList (TaskID, BarcodeID, ScanDataID, Comments, Deadline, UserID, Completed)
SELECT @Job, @BarcodeID, (SELECT ID FROM tbl_PropScanData WHERE BarcodeID = @BarcodeID AND [Location] = @Location), @TaskNotes, @Deadline, @UserID, 0

END
```

Here is an example of the returned row data

```
Job BarcodeID    Location   UserID   Deadline   TaskNotes

61  BarcodeID-1   Test      CAD     2017-01-09  Greenhouse

61  BarcodeID-1   TEST2     CAD     2017-01-09  Greenhouse

61  BarcodeID-1   TEST3     CAD     2017-01-09  Greenhouse
```

In the front end of my platform, the user has the ability to select all the 'Locations' at once to assign the task and other data to all the rows associated.

With the procedure I have now, the user can individually update each of these tasks. Unfortunately, they now have to walk across our facility, scan the barcode, and update the task for the product in that location. It would be much more efficient if they could scan the barcode once, and assign locations to the task via the front end and the procedure assigns the rest of the static data to the server with each individual location. I just need the individual locations to be different.

I hope that helps, it is kind of hard to explain over the web.

Comment: Start by specifying your database engine and programming language for the front end.

Comment: Probably SQL Server.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this `I need my procedure to assign all of the same data to the rows except for the different 'Locations'.` with examples

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve.  Could you include some sample data and expected results?  Also, keep in mind that with SQL you want to think in terms of sets more than loops. It's very rare that you actually want to create a loop in SQL (the database engine does that for you)

Comment: I edited the body to hopefully explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Your textual explanation is not too clear. As @DanField suggests, can you illustrate with data and the ideal preferred output with a given user input?  You show three rows of output? Was the stored procedure called three times? It sounds like you want same data in all columns but different *locations*. How to tell such locations? Plus output shows different locations.

Comment: The output is three separate calls of the stored procedure, updating the location each time. I am trying to get it so that I can call the procedure once and it submits the data output above through one submission of data.  I want the same output as above, just through one call, not 3 individual (updating the location for each row).